# How to remove recurring totals information for a particular subscription product?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a subscription product in which I have customized checkout page for this particular product. I want to remove "Recurring Totals" row from checkout and cart page.

Here is my code:

```
function cart_subtotal_func_unset( $total ) {
    print_r($total);
    unset($totals['cart_subtotal']);
    return $totals;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'cart_subtotal_func_unset', 10, 2);
```

And here is my screenshot for checkout page.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try filtering the hook woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees.

Use this code. it might work for you.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_recurring_postage_fees', 10, 1 );

function add_recurring_postage_fees( $cart ) {
    if ( ! empty( $cart->recurring_cart_key ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total', array( 'WC_Subscriptions_Cart', 'display_recurring_totals' ), 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', array( 'WC_Subscriptions_Cart', 'display_recurring_totals' ), 10 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pawan. You are rockkk.